# CustomStringConvertible in enum

Tags: swift3, enums, customstringconvertible

I have following enum in a class.

```
enum Attributes: String, CustomStringConvertible {
    case eventDate
    case eventName
    case eventType
    case country

    var description: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}
```

When I try have the following code, compiler complains with following error.

```
var attributesList: [String] {
    return [
        Attributes.eventDate, //<-- Compiler error on this row
        Attributes.eventName,
        Attributes.eventType,
        Attributes.country]
}
```

> Cannot convert value of the type 'Attributes' to expected element type 'String'

Shouldn't the "CustomStringConvertible" protocol return the "description"?
What is wrong in the above code?

Comment: If someone wants to down vote a question then that person should have the courtesy to explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** - It doesn't work because an array of `Attribute`s cannot be assigned to an array of `String`s, they are both mismatched types, and Swift does not do automatic conversion between *types*, and an explict conversion needs to be specified.

---

In Swift, when you initialise an array using an array literal, the following happens under the hood:

```
let words = ["hello", "world"]
```

- The compiler recognises that an array literal is being assigned to a variable named `words`. Since we have not specified the type of the `words`, implicitly an array is assumed. The type of the elements underlying the array is determined based on the contents of the array literal.
- In this case, the array literal is a collection of `String` types; this is easily understood by the compiler
- Since the LHS type is an array, the RHS structure is an array literal, and since the LHS type (`Array`) conforms to a pre-defined protocol called `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` which has an associated type constraint to match `Element`, the compiler will actually be converting our line to the following

Example:

```
let words = [String].init(arrayLiteral: ["hello", "world"]) // we do not call this init directly
```

This is how initialising with array literals work. In the above example, since we did not specify the type of array, the implicit type setting will work. If we specified a mismatched type, the assignment will fail, since `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` requires the associated `Element` type of the array literal and the actual array you are assigning to to match.

So the following fails:

```
let words:[String] = [1, 2] // array literal has Element=Int, array has Element=String
```

This also shows that there is no implicit type conversion between `Int` and `String`, even though `Int` conform to `CustomStringConvertible`.

In your case, you are trying to assign an array literal consisting of `Attributes` to an array of `String`. This is a type mismatch. This is the reason it fails.

If you state protocol conformance, the following line will work:

```
var attributesList: [CustomStringConvertible] {
    return [
        Attributes.eventDate,
        Attributes.eventName,
        Attributes.eventType,
        Attributes.country
    ]
}
// note that we have an array of CustomStringConvertible protocol,
// each element here is still of Attributes type
// a type conforming to a protocol can be cast to an instance
// of that protocol automatically
// The above initialisation works simply because the following
// also works without any further action required
// let a:CustomStringConvertible = Attributes.country
```

If you really want a list of string values, you need to map this to a string explicitly:

```
var attributesList1: [String] {
    return [
        Attributes.eventDate,
        Attributes.eventName,
        Attributes.eventType,
        Attributes.country
        ].map { $0.description }
}

var attributesList2: [String] {
    return [
        Attributes.eventDate.description,
        Attributes.eventName.description,
        Attributes.eventType.description,
        Attributes.country.description
        ]
}
```

Comment: Or you can use `rawValue` instead of `description` in the final example.